# Android - Coroutines slower than RX Completable when calculating in a long for loop

Tags: android, rx-java, kotlin-coroutines

Trying a simple application where one uses coroutines to add a `variable i` and another uses a `Completable` from `RxJava`.

Coroutine code:

```
val timeCoroutineStart = System.currentTimeMillis()
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        var i = 0
        repeat(1000000000) {
            i++
        }
        Log.d(
            "TASK_TIME",
            "COROUTINE: ${System.currentTimeMillis() - timeCoroutineStart}"
        )
    }.start()
```

Rx code:

```
val timeRxStart = System.currentTimeMillis()
Completable.create{
        var i = 0
        repeat(1000000000) {
            i++
        }
        it.onComplete()
    }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe {
        Log.d(
            "TASK_TIME",
            "RX: ${System.currentTimeMillis() - timeRxStart}"
        )
    }
```

Result:

```
D/TASK_TIME: RX: 1720
D/TASK_TIME: COROUTINE: 20873
```

I'm fairly new using coroutines and wanted to try something very simple. It's worth noting that in smaller for loops coroutines is `MUCH faster`. Am I using it wrong? Or coroutines has a drawback in longer calculation than RX?

**Edit**

Running the Coroutine code on a JVM (Not Android) has a very similar to Rx, so exact same code running on Android has a different performance then went run on JVM

Comment: interesting. May be coroutines utilizing rx inside. lol

Comment: This could be due to any sorts of things: wrong benchmark methodology, old library, etc. If I run the code repeatedly with Kotlin 1.3.50, coroutines 1.3 and RxJava 3.0.0-RC7. Initially both print 55 milliseconds, then 0 pretty much after that. https://gist.github.com/akarnokd/fef7a5cfe3fad98f8b8a8a1cc8dfffcc

Comment: @akarnokd I am using coroutines version 1.3.3 and Kotlin version 1.3.61. Is your snippet running on an android app ?

Comment: Desktop app. I'm currently evaluating an Android variant.

Comment: I tested your code and indeed they run both in around 20ms. It's the same code yet performs differently on Android.

Comment: It's peculiar. If I move the repeat part into its own method, I get pretty much the same result for both cases on Androd. I don't know how to investigate the coroutines part further so consider posting on their issue list.

Comment: @akarnokd Which part did you move to it's own function? Would you mind sharing that code please?

Comment: The `var i = 0; repeat (1000000000) { i++ }`.